# How do you copy and paste formulas exactly as is in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large number of formulas I need to copy and paste without changing cell references, but excel keeps changing it.
I also want to do it without replacing the = sign in the formula. There are multiple = signs in the formula and in other places in the worksheet that I do not want to risk screwing up.
You cannot tell me that excel has been out for this long and there is no simple way to copy and paste formulas without changing the reference.

Comment: "You cannot tell me that excel has been out for this long and there is no simple way to copy and paste formulas without changing the reference." who is telling you that?

Comment: Use absolute cell references?

Comment: @Blind Spots the fact I've i'd tried to google a solution and literally none of them works?

Comment: The rude comment by the author in Blind Spots solution below reflects the actual question, which is nothing like the question written above.

Comment: Copy to the TEXT first and then re-copy and paste to cells.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great resource for the many different options for copying and pasting formulas in Excel.

**Ablebits blog:** [How to copy formula in Excel](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/copy-formula-excel/#:%7E:text=Select%20all%20the%20cells%20with,to%20paste%20the%20formulas%20there).

You identified in comments ways that 2 approaches for your use case fail you:

1. Cell references when copied between documents include references to the original workbook and worksheet.
2. Temporarily replacing equals signs in formulas is undesirable to you because you have "multiple = signs in the formula and in other places in the worksheet" that you "do not want to risk screwing up."

You see a worksheet and workbook reference being introduced on paste.  I see a relative reference to a worksheet and workgroup being explicitly written at a point when that is the only way to maintain it and to do otherwise would break the formula (which I do appreciate is your goal).

Selectively and arbitrarily changing formulas in Excel on paste is undesirable in a multitude of use cases even if useful in your own limited case.

The approaches in both #1 and #2 above seem appropriate for your problem space, meet your needs, and are the simplest and safest way to achieve your goals.  They require almost no additional time and effort other than a few keystrokes and as such the arguments against using them seem unconvincing.

1. In the case of the included workbook/worksheet name, it is a matter of a simple **Replace All** (CTRL + F > Replace > Replace All) to globally remove the offending references ("[workBookName.ext]") if the sheet names are the same or ("'[workBookName.ext]SheetName!'") if they are different.  Quick, easy, all references are now broken (fixed you would say) as you prefer.
2. Replacing the equals signs is an excellent way to achieve what you want since it provides an easy way to convert to text strings and back without damaging your formulas.  Replacing all the equals signs in a selection with a string that does not run the risk of bumping into anything in the real world is child's play, and runs little risk of screwing anything up.

In my case, after selecting the cells to copy, but prior to copying, I would **Replace All** (CTRL + F > Replace > Replace All)  "=" with "XXXXX".  I use 5 X's so that there is no chance that there is something in any of my formulas that has "XXXXX" and will get messed up when I put the "=" back.

After pasting my formulas wherever they need to go, I would again **Replace All** (CTRL + F > Replace > Replace All)  to replace all instances of "XXXXX" with "=" in the old and new locations.  Hardly more time than just copying and pasting.

If you know that you are very prone to making mistakes in operations like this, I recommend versioning your documents and/or backing up so you can roll back to before you made your errors.

---

**Should you try a different approach?**

The devil's in the details when it comes to problem solving, and what works for one person may not fit another's use case.

If the bulk of your workflow involves breaking cell references, it is possible that backing up a few spaces and examining what you are trying to accomplish may expose alternative approaches ([XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)) that don't rely heavily on copying and pasting functions between workbooks.

---

#### For your interest

Off topic but thought I would throw it in.

**LAMBDA**
If you find that you have a lot of reuse of complex custom formulas and that is why you want to copy them, you might look into LAMBDA (named) functions.  It is relatively new functionality in Excel to create custom, reusable functions and call them by friendly names. [Microsoft LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67)

There is also information out there about sharing across workbooks.

This is probably one of the easiest approaches with a small hack: [YouTube: Using LAMBDA functions across multiple workbooks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IPP4MVb25mU)

Comment: Are you even reading the question? I need a way to copy and paste formulas EXACTLY as is and that is not a solution. The formula is already using absolute references. However, if I try to copy and paste formulas from a workbook to another, it keeps the reference of the previous workbook which I do NOT want, and I need it to basically be copied and pasted AS TEXT except I do not want the formulas be converted to text.

Comment: I would have proposed you the same solution as user "Blind Spots" and I was reading your question.
I am using Excel over 20 years and I never had your need. For your case I would write a VBA makro as two nested loop to copy a rectangular area. Would try to access the exact text by using myText=Application.WorksheetFunction.FORMULATEXT()

Comment: Why don't you improve your question instead of including all the missing pearls in your commemts

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for an individual cell by using CTRL C to copy from the formula bar, then press esc to remove the highlight, then enter the formula bar of the new cell and CTRL V to paste the formula in the new location.

To copy multiple you can change the format to text, ensure all of the formulas are showing (i.e. not the results of the calculation - you can do this by clicking individually in each cell containing a formula I am not sure if there is a better way) then copy and pastevalues into the new location. Then change the format back to general and activate the cells by clicking in them if necessary.

Alternatively the solution posted [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/copy-formula-excel/#:%7E:text=Select%20all%20the%20cells%20with,to%20paste%20the%20formulas%20there.)
involves copying a range of cells to notepad first, then back to excel.

Here is a macro solution in case it helps:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Formula_Copy()
Dim x As Range, y As Range
Dim n As Long, i As Long
Set x = Application.InputBox("Select range of cells containing formulae to copy:", "Range Selection", Type:=8)
Set y = Application.InputBox("Select first cell of output range", "Range Selection", Type:=8)
For n = 1 To x.Columns.Count
    For i = 1 To x.Rows.Count
        y.Offset(i - 1, n - 1).Formula = x.Cells(i, n).Formula
    Next i
Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to copy individual cells, but I have way more I need to copy and it would be faster to copy multiple cells at once. How do you change the format to text and keep the formula showing? To me when I change the format to text, the result of the formula is still showing.

Comment: I have added a couple of edits, the only way I know of getting the formulas to show (and having the copy work) is to click in and press enter on each formula containing cell after changing the format to text. There may be a better way, I will keep trying.